# Out of memory on a byte allocation (Bitmap as String to webservice using soap)

Tags: android, bitmap, arrays, ksoap2

Am having a `bitmap` , so I want to upload a webserivceas string  and want to retrive the string.

For converting bitmap to string am using:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();

strBase64 = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.URL_SAFE);
```

this above `String` is using as property to in soapobject to upload.

But am getting `Out of memory on a 11674900-byte allocation`, while print and uploading.

And if i debugged the issue, without printing am getting

```
com.sun.jdi.InvocationException occurred invoking method.
```

on `soaprequest.`

How to resolve this issue and to `upload image` to webservice as string ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are creating 3 copies of an 11MB image(`bitmap`, `stream`, `strBase64`). So reduce the memory usage by calling

```
bitmap.recycle();
```

below this line:

```
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
```

Also close the stream when you are done with it(below `stream.toByteArray();`):

```
stream.close();
stream = null;
```

**Remember that there is no guarantee that memory will be cleaned immediately after these calls**. Proper way to handle this type of situation is to transfer large files chunk by chunk.

Comment: it solved by bytes array and have used serialization before soap request.

Comment: @Udayakiran,I am having same error , what you mentioned in question.So please tell the way you fixed this issue.

Answer (score 0):

An 11 Million byte allocation much larger than most phones' heap can handle. you definitely don't want to be holding a byte array of that size in memory.

Try using insample size with

BitmapFactory.decodeStream(InputStream is, Rect outPadding, BitmapFactory.Options opts)

and settings options to use insample size to return a reasonably sized image.

Comment: Are you saying storing 11mb of data in memory is not possible on android phones?

Comment: It might be possible, but either your phone does not have that much free memory left or it cannot deallocate memory as fast as your are allocating it.

Answer (score -1):

A simple fix for some might be to add **android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"** to your manifest.  In my case, the Nexus_S emulator was crashing without this line, while the actual Nexus 7 device I was testing on wasn't crashing on rotation.

Adding this appears to be an easy fix for apps that have a couple large "match_parent" bitmaps to rotate and resize.

Careful if you are building for APIs before 13!